# Odoo Qweb show for contact

Tags: odoo, qweb

I am currently working on  Odoo (v8) template and want to show  contact person name only for customer. What currently works is:

```
      <span  t-field="o.partner_id.child_ids"  t-field-options='{"widget":  "contact", "fields": [ "name"], "no_marker": true}' />
```

the output is:

```
   Cathirine,Tak
```

**My question is**: How can I write to show only contact name as:

```
   Tak
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
class SaleOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    contact_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', 'Contact',
                                 domain="[('parent_id','=',partner_id)]")
```

Then call

```
<strong>Dear: <span t-field="o.contact_id.name"/></strong><br/>
```

Comment: <span t-field="o.contact_id.name"/>